# Rails3 generate custom javaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

An object, which is essentially a polygon, has an array of attributes (longitude and latitude).

```
class Polygon
  has_many :lonlats
class Lonlat
  belongs_to :polygon
  attr_accessible :lon, :lat
```

I have to initialize a javaScript for the Polygon object's show view, invoking an indeterminate amount of lonlats, example:

```
  var polygonCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(36.23, 19.55),
    new google.maps.LatLng(36.17, 19.53),
    new google.maps.LatLng(36.03, 19.89),
    new google.maps.LatLng(36.12, 19.90)
  ];
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the script is individualised, generate the script in the view :

```
   <% @lonlats.each do |lonlat| %>
      new google.maps.LatLng(<%= lonlat.lat %>, <%= lonlat.lon %>)<%= "," unless lonlat == @lonlats.last %>
    <% end %>
```

controller:

```
   @lonlats = Lonlat.where(['polygon_id = ?', params[:id]]).all
```